# Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error

Tags: sass

I've npm installed the latest node-sass, and scss files work fine until I use @use. I have a _tokens.scss file in /shared/tokens/ folder. Within _tokens.scss I have:

```
$colorwhite: #ffffff;
```

In my root folder, my App.scss looks like this:

```
@use "shared/tokens/tokens";

.App-header {
  color: tokens.$colorwhite;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/App.scss)
SassError: Invalid CSS after "  color: tokens": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$colorwhite;"
        on line 26 of /Users/xxx/src/App.scss
>>   color: tokens.$colorwhite;
```

Any ideas?

Edit: it works fine with `@import`. I've also tried `@use... as *` but no-go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Update:

Since [**Node Sass** is now deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated), you can migrate to **Dart Sass** by replacing `node-sass` with `sass` in your `package.json` and so you will be able to use the `@use` and `@forward` rules.

You can use the [migration tool](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/migrator) to help you with the update.

---

#### Original answer:

The [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) rule is currently only supported by **Dart Sass**. You should use [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) instead.

Comment: Thanks - I discovered that a second ago and came back to update the issue because I didn't see it in the docs. I looked into the sass package and decided node-sass is more popular and supposedly the more performant so I'll live with ```@import``` until ```@use``` is supported by node-sass.

Comment: You're not the only one who didn't see it at first, the compatibility is not very visible in the docs...

Answer (score 3):

You could switch to **Dart Sass** by taking advantage of `package-aliasing`. I guess this will not work under `yarn`.

First you remove the current `node-sass` pkg, then run:

`npm install node-sass@npm:sass`.

And you are fit to use the full features from `sass` with some remarks though.

- Check the behavioral diffs [here](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass).
- The performance measurement indicates that `dart-sass` is slower than `node-sass`.

It's all up to you and this turns to be a valid option here, if you really want to use these features provided by `Sass`.

Comment: Working with `react-scripts: 3.4.3` using yarn.