# Why do I keep getting Uknown at rule @use?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using sass.

When I type

```
@use "nav";
```

I keep getting the error message

```
Uknown at rule @use (scssuknownAtRules)
```

it also gets compiled to css as @use

I have the latest version of sass,
i've tried installing and uninstalling.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the "nav.scss" file in the same folder as that main file?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343131/trying-to-use-sass-modules-in-create-react-app-with-the-new-use-syntax-but-rece)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use):

> The @use rule loads mixins, functions, and variables from other Sass stylesheets, and combines CSS from multiple stylesheets together. Stylesheets loaded by @use are called "modules". Sass also provides built-in modules full of useful functions.

Also,

> A stylesheet’s @use rules must come before any rules other than @forward, including style rules. However, you can declare variables before @use rules to use when configuring modules.

Since you haven't shared your entire file, I would make sure that "nav" fits the description detailed above and is referenced correctly.

Comment: nav.scss is in the same folder and that is all of the code provided

Comment: @RyanHinchliffe - can you share the contents of nav? Have you tried importing it using the full path?