# How do I use sass variables from another sass file

Tags: css, sass

I am developing a WordPress theme and I am trying to use sass from another file using the `@use` method but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I fix the problem since the `@import` rule method will be depreciated soon?
I have files

```
//_brand.scss
$base-color: #c6538c;
$border-dark: rgba($base-color, 0.88);
```

and then

```
//footer.scsss
@use 'brand' as b;
.footer{
    padding: 0px 5%;
    background-color: b.$base-color;
}
```

and I get this error when it's compiling

```
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "...ground-color: b": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$font-size;"
        on line 5 of sass/opt/lampp/.../sass/footer.scss
>>     background-color: b.$base-color;
```

I am using "Live Sass Compiler" visual studio code extension to compile to CSS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343131/trying-to-use-sass-modules-in-create-react-app-with-the-new-use-syntax-but-rece)

Comment: Maybe. Does that mean I use import even when it's depreciated?

Comment: @iamafasha Yes, or you need to use Dart Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the variables you have defined within the `brand.scss` file across different files, you can use the `@import` directive. For using it, just add the line below to your `footer.scss` file:

```
@import "brand";
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_import.asp

I hope my answer will help you

Comment: Okay, this worked though am worried about the depreciation issue. The use of import in sass is about to be depreciated.

Comment: You could create a partial and then import, so that it doesn't get compiled.