# How can I include and use an external variable file using Sass '@use' command?

Tags: css, sass

I'm having trouble importing and using variables from a separate variables.sass file using Sass' @use command. I am splitting the code into files and folders trying to follow the SMACSS standard. The basic structure of my project is as follows:

```
- sass(root folder)
  |- app.sass
  |- _index.sass
  |- _variables.sass
  |- base
     |- _base-dir.sass
     |- _base.sass
```

The content of app.sass:

```
@use "index"
```

The content of _index.sass:

```
@use "variables" as v /*I'm assigning the variables to a namespace called v */
@use "base/base-dir"
```

The content of _variables.sass:

```
$theme-color-primary: #e6e6e6
```

The content of _base-dir.sass:

```
@use "base"
```

And finally, the content of _base.sass:

```
html
    color: v.$theme-color-primary !important
```

However, Sass wont compile this, complaining that:

```
Error: There is no module with the namespace "v".
  ╷
2 │     color: v.$theme-color-primary !important
  │            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  sass\base\_base.sass 2:12     @use
  sass\base\_base-dir.sass 1:1  @use
  sass\_index.sass 3:1          @use
  sass\app.sass 1:1             root stylesheet
```

Additionally, replacing `as v` with `as *` in _index.sass (to import the file without a namespace as stated [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace)), and removing the prefix `v.` when calling the variable results in a variable-not-declared error.

I can circumvent this issue by using `@import` instead of `@use`, but Sass has stated that the improt command will be phased out in future versions and the use command should be preferred, so I'm trying to do the nice thing.}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343131/trying-to-use-sass-modules-in-create-react-app-with-the-new-use-syntax-but-rece)

Comment: Hi @Arkellys. I downloaded the dart-sass window installer from the official Sass download site. The answer suggests that ```@use``` only works with dart-sass, so I should be fine using it in this way. I'm still confused.